# How can I implement date range selection in Angular 8?

Tags: angular-material, angular8, date-range

Hey I am trying to implement date range selection input in my project. The angular version I am using is Angular 8, the mat-date-range-input is available from Angular 10 version. Are there any alternatives?

I tried using mat-datepicker toggle and capture 2 dates, but still the UI will be in such a way that only one date is selected.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.